# How to handle INVALID_JOIN_ON_EXPRESSION error in ClickHouse SQL?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

What is the most efficient SQL equivalent for this in ClickHouse?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id and t1.date >= t2.valid_from_date and t1.date < t2.valid_to_date
```

The Code works in PostgreSQL but not in ClickHouse. It results in a INVALID_JOIN_ON_EXPRESSION error.

The expected behaviour is to keep all rows from table1 and only join the information from table2 if the IDs match and the date is between valid_from_date and valid_to_date.

Comment: Maybe you're missing the alias `t2` on `table2`?

Comment: I edited my post, the alias was not missing in my original query. Clickhouse prohibits joins on expressions like >, < or between. I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately, ClickHouse doesn't support non equal join expressions ;(